# javascript smooth scrolling down a page

Tags: javascript

Just wondering if there was any way which you can use javascript in order to have smooth scrolling down a page. I don't mean href's like `#section1` ect. I mean actual mouse wheel scrolling. I have looked all over this site and the internet but all I can find is the smooth href scrolling, not smooth mouse wheel scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is surely possible.

I assume you don't want to build it from scratch, so here's a [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/fatlinesofcode/jquery.smoothwheel).

What this plugin does is to listen to `mousewheel` and `DOMMouseScroll` events, and executes a custom, smooth scroll when they're triggered.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: [Smooth scrolling demo](http://web.archive.org/web/20140213105950/http://itnewb.com/tutorial/Creating-the-Smooth-Scroll-Effect-with-JavaScript)

You can try something like this:

1. Get the current top location using self.pageYOffset
2. Get the position of element till where you want to scroll to: element.offsetTop
3. Do a for loop to reach there, which will be quite fast or use a timer to do smooth scroll till that position using window.scrollTo

NOTE: Solution is just rough idea, not crossbrowser at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it with jquery without any plugin, and you can even decide how much time the scrolling should take.

For instance, if you have an element with id `scrollhere` in the point you want to reach, and attach a click listener that will start the animation to a button or a link with id `scroll`:

```
$("#scroll").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#scrollHere").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: if i want to add a button to move to  the page top : scrollBottom:$('#top').offset().bottom   
but this code didn't work ...

Comment: For the page top just do `scrollTop: 0`