# html javascript smooth scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to smooth scroll using JavaScript? I want to **Smooth Scroll Down To Div** Can anyone know how to add smooth scroll in the JavaScript code below

```js
function scroll_to(val) {
 if(val== "Scroll down to div id")  
    document.getElementById('divid11').scrollIntoView();
}
```

```html
<select onchange="scroll_to(this.value);">
<option>1111111</option>
<option>2222222</option>
<option >Scroll down to div id</option>
<option>4444444</option>
<option>5555555</option>
<option>6666666</option>
</select>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <div id='divid11'>scroll</div>
```

Comment: Where is the "Scroll" here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery smooth scrolling when clicking an anchor link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717527/jquery-smooth-scrolling-when-clicking-an-anchor-link)

Comment: @allicarn it is only tagged, but it don't use jQuery !

Comment: if jQuery is not part of the question, OP should remove the tag.

Comment: @allicarn, yes you're right !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript smooth scrolling down a page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29716730/javascript-smooth-scrolling-down-a-page)

Answer (score 2):

This is in general already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717527/jquery-smooth-scrolling-when-clicking-an-anchor-link). So using JQuerys `.animate` function in combination of `ScrollTop` will do the trick for you.

For doing this without JQuery you can follow [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20140213105950/http://itnewb.com/tutorial/Creating-the-Smooth-Scroll-Effect-with-JavaScript) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Use this script in your body for smooth scroll.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
                var target = $(this.hash);
                target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
                if (target.length) {
                    $('html,body').animate({
                        scrollTop: target.offset().top
                    }, 1000);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```